# Create a breakdown of the total revenue per month

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a list of clients that worked with us and show how much they spent per month. I made this query below but the numbers are not matching. Do you have any suggestions on how this can be adjusted? Thank you.

```
months_counter as 
(SELECT date_trunc('month', job.date) as week,
        client.company_name as company,
        sum(job.client_charge) as count

 FROM client
 left join job on job.client_id = client.id
 left join user on user.id = client.user_id
 left JOIN booking ON booking.job_id = job.id
 WHERE user.date_joined > '04-01-2021'
  group by 1,2
 
 )


select 
 company,
        coalesce(sum(CASE
               WHEN week=date_trunc('month',NOW())-interval '6 month' THEN COUNT
               ELSE NULL
           END), 0) AS "April",
           
       coalesce(sum(CASE
               WHEN week=date_trunc('month',NOW())-interval '5 month' THEN COUNT
               ELSE NULL
           END), 0) AS "May",
           
       coalesce(sum(CASE
               WHEN week=date_trunc('month',NOW())-interval '4 month' THEN COUNT
               ELSE NULL
           END), 0) AS "June"
           
from months_counter
 group by 1
```

Comment: Please spend a few minuets an take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. In particular post sample data, as text- **no images**,  or even better a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13), the results you get and the results you expect from that data.  Your saying *numbers are not matching* does not help when we cannot see them.

Comment: In the first SELECT, the clause `left JOIN booking ON booking.job_id = job.id` seems useless and could be removed. Then does this first `SELECT` provides the expected results?